# Create multiple objects (of similar type) with single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say I have a form for adding names and photos of dogs.

I would like to add up to 10 dogs on a single form.. and have any blank fields ignored...

How can I actually create such a form, and what would the controller action look like that would handle the form?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you'd want a sort of dynamic form, like Ryan Bates does on this RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

You might want to check out [the previous episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) for rejecting the blank "dogs" too.